# Query result in a daily date from a date range selection Postgres 9.3

Tags: postgresql, date, format

I need to make a report that will output a result in a daily row result based on the datarange selected.

Example:

```
Table: sales
->id
->type
->gross
->created_at
->updated_at
```

For example my query is

```
SELECT COUNT(case when type = 'Completed Sale' then id end) as complete, 
       COUNT(case when disposition = 'Partial Sale' then id end) as partial, 
       SUM(gross)as revenue 
FROM sales 
WHERE created_at >= '2015-09-20 00:43:32' AND created_at <= '2015-09-24 18:43:32';
```

The range is Sept 20 to Sept 24

So basically the output will be like:

```
complete | partial | revenue
1          1         2.3
```

What I want the output to be like this

```
start date | end date    | complete | partial | revenue
___________|_____________|__________|_________|____________
2015-09-20 | 2015-09-21  | 1        | 1       | 2.3
2015-09-21 | 2015-09-22  | 3        | 4       | 4.3
2015-09-22 | 2015-09-23  | 3        | 4       | 4.3
2015-09-23 | 2015-09-24  | 4        | 4       | 3.3
```

So as you can see, the output is the daily basis of the start date and end date. If choose 1 month range then there will be 30 or 31. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All that you have to add is the day (be it the start or the end date).  This can be obtained using a cast to `date`, for example.  When you add it to the query, you'll need a `GROUP BY` clause, too, on this expression - that will produce you the daily aggregates.

The whole query will look like

```
SELECT created_at::date AS start_date,
       created_at::date + 1 AS end_date,
       COUNT(case when type = 'Completed Sale' then id end) AS complete, 
       COUNT(case when disposition = 'Partial Sale' then id end) AS partial, 
       SUM(gross) AS revenue 
FROM sales 
WHERE created_at >= '2015-09-20 00:43:32' AND created_at <= '2015-09-24 18:43:32'
GROUP BY created_at::date;
```

**Notes:**

- using `start_date` and `end_date` like this can be slightly confusing - in normal life one expects the end date to be inclusive.  With the way you use it might not be clear which data belong to which day - I would simply omit the end date.
- in the `GROUP BY` clause it's enough to mention the cast expression only once - adding one day in another columns does not result in a different grouping.

Comment: OMG it works. Thank you so much and for the explanation. I thought this is not possible so I'm thinking that I'll just do the manipulation in PHP but anyway. Thanks!